# "Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@'" when using lit component with NextJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, polymer, lit

I try to import a lit component in my NextJS project.

Here is my component:

```js
import {html, css, LitElement} from 'lit';
import {customElement} from 'lit/decorators.js';

@customElement('my-element')
export class MyElement extends LitElement {
    static get styles() {
        ...
    }

    render () {
        return html`
            <div>Hello World !</div>
        `;
    }
}

declare global {
    interface HTMLElementTagNameMap {
        'my-element': MyElement;
    }
}
```

Here is my NextJS element:

```js
import '.../my-element';

function HomePage() {
    return (
        <div>
            <my-element label="coucou"/>
            <div>coucou</div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default HomePage
```

Here is the output:

```
.../my-element.ts
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (20:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|  */
| 
> @customElement('my-element')
| export class MyElement extends LitElement {
|     static get styles() {
```

I am new to NextJS and React.
Is it really a Webpack issue or should I fix somehow my element ?

Comment: decorators like @customElement usually needs you to update the build config. Do you have a babel plugin for this maybe ?

Comment: check the "Enabling decorators" section here: https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/decorators

Comment: I've added the babel config but there is still the error.

Answer (score 1):

you need to make sure you have these babel plugins setup:

- @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators.
- @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties

```js
plugins = [
  '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
  ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', {decoratorsBeforeExport: true}],
];
```

Comment: I did what you've said but the result is the same:

I've created a `.babelrc` file which contains:
```json
{
    "presets": ["next/babel"],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", {"decoratorsBeforeExport": true}]
    ]
}
```

I also added `"experimentalDecorators": true,` to my `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: have you restarted your build script after updating the config ?

Comment: Maybe it because my component is actually in a npm packages that I have installed.
Should I change something so the babel config is applied for my package ?

Comment: I don't think so. What's the extension of your file ? try to change it to '.ts' or '.tsx' and see if that work maybe

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, were you able to find a solution to this?